# how to use angular material theme colour variables in other scss files

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material2, angular8

for a school assignment we need to use angular material. I made a custom theme called: `weather-theme.scss`

the code in this file is as following:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$weather-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-gray, 800, 700, 600);
$weather-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-amber, 800, 700);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$weather-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$weather-theme-theme: mat-light-theme(
    $weather-theme-primary,
    $weather-theme-accent,
    $weather-theme-warn
);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($weather-theme-theme);
```

the theme works.

and i import the theme in `styles.scss` with the code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap');

@import './weather-theme.scss';
//@import './variables.scss';

html,
body {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

now the problem is, I want to use the Theme variables in other styles like i want to give the body the primary colour from that the code is like this:

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    background-color: $weather-theme-primary;
}
```

but when i import the `weather-theme.scss` the variables are reconized by the scss intellisense it doesn't work, and i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/scss/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    background-color: $weather-theme-primary;
                     ^
      (50: #fafafa, 100: #f5f5f5, 200: #eeeeee, 300: #e0e0e0, 400: #bdbdbd, 500: #9e9e9e, 600: #757575, 700: #616161, 800: #424242, 900: #212121, A100: #ffffff, A200: #eeeeee, A400: #bdbdbd, A700: #616161, contrast: (50: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 200: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 300: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 400: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 500: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 600: white, 700: white, 800: white, 900: white, A100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), A200: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), A400: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), A700: white), default: #424242, lighter: #616161, darker: #757575, text: #424242, default-contrast: white, lighter-contrast: white, darker-contrast: white, "50-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "100-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "200-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "300-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "400-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "500-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "600-contrast": white, "700-contrast": white, "800-contrast": white, "900-contrast": white, "A100-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "A200-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "A400-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "A700-contrast": white, "contrast-contrast": null) isn't a valid CSS value.
   ╷
13 │     background-color: $weather-theme-primary;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  stdin 13:23  root stylesheet
      in /media/sean-paul/Data/Projects/School/CSP/OpenWeatherAngularApp/src/scss/styles.scss (line 13, column 23)
```

what am i doing wrong here?

**note: i use angular 8**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable is a map. You have to declare which attribute you want.

```
background-color: map-get($weather-theme-primary, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$weather-theme-primary` you created in your `weather-theme.scss` doesn't contain a single value, but a whole palette. See the name of the mixin you created it with, and also in the error message, you can see the actual object being dumped (`... 50: #fafafa, 100: #f5f5f5, ...`, where `50` is the first key, `#fafafa` is the color for that, `100` is the 2nd key, `#f5f5f5` is color for that, etc...).

You can extract values from the map the following way:

```
$my-color: map-get($weather-theme-primary, 50)
```

and then that color can be used in actual scss rules.